# Is there a simple operation on two sets that determines whether one is a subset of another?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking for a simple function on two sets that does the following:
1) If either set is a subset of the other set, the function returns the smaller set.
2) Otherwise, it returns the empty set.

Can I construct such a function with elementary set operations (union, intersection, complement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that taking power set is an operation then let $P(A)$ be the set of all subsets if $A$. Then $$(P(A)\cap\{B\})\cup (P(B)\cap \{A\})$$ will give us either empty set or $\{A\}$ or $\{B\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$a \subseteq b \iff a \cap b = a$

However, if $a \not\subseteq b$, it is not necessary that $a \cap b = \varnothing$, so you probably need some branching.

Comment: This doesn't return the empty set if neither contains the other, but I think it's the best you can do.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't construct exactly what you want. The reason is that elementary set operations only cares about single elements at a time: they ask if each element "Are you part of $A$? Are you part of $B$?" and from the answers to those questions decides whether that point is part of the new set the operation creates.

Set operations do not ask points questions about other points like "are there any points in $A$ which aren't in $B$?" so you can't get the empty set as the result when neither contains the other and at the same time get all of one set when one does contain the other. Elements do not sense the other elements in the sets they are a part of; the only thing they know is whether they themselves are elements of a given set or not. So they can't answer the entire question you want to ask them.

Comment: I think $A\cap B^c$ contains exactly the points of $A$ which are not in $B$?

Comment: @awllower That is true. But that's not what the OP is after. He wants an operation $A\star B$ such that $a\in A\star B$ iff $a\in A$ and $a\in B$ and there either exists no $b\in A\cap B^c$ or there exists no $b\in A^c\cap B$. The first two conditions is just the intersection, which is fine, but that last one contradicts the essence of elementary set operations as I've described them above.

Comment: @awllower I've made it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\require{begingroup}\begingroup\newcommand{f}{\mathcal F}\f(A,B)$ be the family of functions on two sets defined as follows:

- $(A,B)\mapsto A \in \f.$
- $(A,B)\mapsto B \in \f.$
- If $(A,B)\mapsto S \in \f$ then $(A,B)\mapsto S^C \in \f.$
- If $(A,B)\mapsto S \in \f$ and $(A,B)\mapsto T \in \f$ then $(A,B)\mapsto S \cap T \in \f.$
- If $(A,B)\mapsto S \in \f$ and $(A,B)\mapsto T \in \f$ then $(A,B)\mapsto S \cup T \in \f.$

Moreover, $\f$ contains *only* the functions implied by the statements above. 
I think the functions of the kind you meant to describe are all in $\f.$

There are exactly $16$ functions in $\f.$
Each function returns a union of zero or more of the sets $A\cap B,$ $A\cap B^C,$ $A^C\cap B,$ and $A^C\cap B^C.$
We get $16$ functions by deciding, for each of these four sets, whether or not to include it in the function's output.

One can quickly confirm that none of these $16$ functions is the one you want. 
To define the function you want, you will have to admit some other means of defining it. (The definition you have already given seems good to me.)
$\endgroup$